# Tupper's Formula in Prolog

Tags: prolog, bignum

Prolog is said to be very bad for numerics.
Can we prove the contrary and like plot the following function?

[image]

We need to plot the formula where y in a range [k,k+17) for a  very large k,
so bignums
could be helpful. But unfortunately the formula looks like a float formula.

Comment: Does that really work? What are the sets of boolean-valued formulas that generate something that is a reasonable approximation of their own bit pattern (it's certainly NOT self-referential though because it doesn't refer to anyting at all; at best it's self-printing)

Comment: Well, we have rationals based on GMP, so this should be possible, easy. Floats are just rationals on an irregular grid, after all.